# How to Mock function to return a complex value with Pester

Tags: unit-testing, powershell

I have a problem with my pester code in which I should mock a certain function(`Get-State`) to return a complex value so that `$StartState` can have a value. With my level of Powershell I can't seem to create a custom object.

```
    $State  = Get-State

    $StartState = $State.Where({$_.Name -eq "State_SUccess"}).state
```

I tried using a custom object with this code to mock the `Get-State` function

```
    $State = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = "State_SUccess"}
    if($State.Name -eq "State_SUccess""){
    $State = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = @{state = 1}}
    }
    else
    {
    }
    $BatchState.statusName.state
```

But it does not do the trick, the `$StartState`still has no value because maybe I have to create a custom method where?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much info on what you are planning to do but i think it is something like this:

Change the first part to:

```
$State  = Get-State

$StartState = $State.Where({$_.Name -eq "State_SUccess"})
```

and:

```
$State = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = "State_SUccess"}
if($State.Name -eq "State_SUccess")
{
    $State = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = @{state = 1}}
}
else
{
}
$StartState.Name
```

this a rather strange approach...
maybe you need something like this:

```
$State = @{Name = "State_SUccess"}
if($State.Name -eq "State_SUccess")
{
    $State['State'] = 1
}
else
{
}
$StartState
```

Comment: Hi Bert,
Thanks for replying. I can't change the
        $State.Where({$_.Name -eq "State_SUccess"}).state because it already part of the function I am making Pester test with. Any other clues or advice what to do?